# how to get a bird-eye-view image using opencv without knowing the intrinsic patameters of camera

Tags: opencv

I need to get transform some images to bird-eye-view images, how can i do that without knowing the intrinsic parameters of the camera?  And those images dont have an chessboard in them.

Also, is it feesible that i use an image with chessboard in it to get the intrinsic parameters and then use those parameters to transform those images i need to transform? 
Or what should I do to get the images transformed?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to get a bird's view of a plane in your image you could compute a [projective transformation or homography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography).

Select 4 points on the plane of interest in your image, define the four corresponding coordinates of the bird's view and solve the system of linear equations. Take a look at the answer to this question on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog) which explains exactly that.

The also interesting derivation of this transformation can be found in every computer vision text book, e.g. THE standard Zisserman's ["Multiple View Geometry"](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/) or Ma's ["An Invitation to 3-D Vision"](http://vision.ucla.edu/MASKS/).

Bon chance.